# getList() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface

Tags: api, magento2

Been trying to figure out what is going on here, but gotten stuck. Anyone got an idea as to what is going on.

Using Magento 2.2.4

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor::getList() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface, string given in C:\wamp64\www\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor.php on line 85 
( ! ) TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor::getList() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface, string given in C:\wamp64\www\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor.php on line 85
```

[image]

Code I try to execute:

```
set_time_limit(0);
define('TOKEN', 'token code');
define('URL', 'http://localhost:8080/magento2/index.php'); 
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer ". TOKEN);
//API URL to get all Magento 2 modules
$requestUrl = (URL . "/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria=");
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Also posted on the magento stackoverflow, but getting 0 views there, so hoping someone here can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass search Criteria while requesting API. Try below code.

```
set_time_limit(0);
define('TOKEN', 'token code');
define('URL', 'http://localhost:8080/magento2/index.php');
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer ". TOKEN);
//API URL to get all Magento 2 modules
$requestUrl = (URL . "/rest/V1/products/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_gear&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=86&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=finset");
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```